# Unable to install cntk on mac

Tags: macos, docker, cntk

Firsrt of all , I use macOS (High Serria 10.13.6) and have my docker installed.
I have implemented following commands in shell

```
docker pull microsoft/cntk:2.5.1-cpu-python3.5

docker run -d -p 8888:8888 --name cntk-jupyter-notebooks -t microsoft/cntk

docker exec -it cntk-jupyter-notebooks bash -c "source /cntk/activate-cntk && jupyter-notebook --no-browser --port=8888 --ip=0.0.0.0 --notebook-dir=/cntk/Tutorials --allow-root"
```

Then I have received following feedback:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,

to login with a token:

http://0.0.0.0:8890/?token=ecd25750b4aaf098140ee3ccf7941c4414a36efebf67fcb0
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

In the few weeks ago, what I did is just paste the url to my browser. Then cntk can be run. But now when I paste it, it only directs my to the (ordinary) Anaconda-Jupyter-Notebook. And I can't import cntk at all.

Please help !

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/cntk-docker-containers